# the FacebookLogin component in the facebook-react-login library not working

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-login

I used the facebook-react-login library by npm and this is the component that they have used
[image]

I have replaced my appID to keep it hidden, and the callback responseFacebook is defined as follows

[image]

above the response i have defined the prop types.

The issue i am facing is the facebook login component is not working as i am not able to click on it

[image]

this button is not clickable at the moment and I am not able to understand why? is it because I am not getting anything as response from the other side? I think the problem is in the responseFacebook func but I'm not able to figure it out. any help would be appreciated!